# how to Copy data from an existing remote database(MySQL) to another local MySQL database with different schema?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to copy data from a MySQL remote database to an other MySQL database whith different schema (table and column names as well as primary and foreign key constraint)

I want to bring the data from `db1.person` and put it into `db2.user` while mapping `db1.person.id` to `db2.user.id` and the same for the name and email column.

I intend to make this process run twice a week so it would be great to have a script for it.

remote database db1 has table `person`:

- id
- name
- email

local database db2 has table `user`

- id
- name
- email
- group_id

and `group`

- id
- label
- description

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this free database manager http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/ 

DBeaver does a good job copying tables over different schemas or databases.
It has very small footprint and copying is very fast.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh @xerius, but I'm looking for a script so I can perform this action automatically twice a week

Comment: @Saf, There is no small utility like that.  I've searched for it recently. Then I decided to write my own code in java to copy tables using Jdbc. It can be scheduled easily.

Comment: I think I will write a python script to collect all the data I need from the first database and then insert them into the second database using simple SQL queries.